# Subdomain not created

Tags: web-hosting, subdomain

I am trying to create a sub domain like `labs.7sisters.in` for the folder with document root `public_html/7sislabs` . If I visit the site http://7sisters.in/7sislabs/ its working fine . But http://labs.7sisters.in , its showing something else ! I don't have the cgi-bin directory there .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) In the case of "http://7sisters.in/7sislabs/", the web server should have a subdirectory "sislabs" under it's document root.

2) In the case of "http://labs.7sisters.in", your DNS should be configured to have some host "labs.7sisters.in", and the web server on that host should probably be configured for a virtual server "labs".

3) Each server and each virtual server can be configured to have its own cgi-bin (or any other resource directory), and the configuration may alias the same physical directory, or may point to different directories.  Your choice :)

Comment: My pleasure.  Here's a short tutorial that gives you a flavor of setting up virtual servers on Apache.  On IIS, of course, it's just point-and-click:  http://ubuntu-tutorials.com/2008/01/09/setting-up-name-based-virtual-hosting/